# How to fade out a titleView label on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiviewanimation, ios12

I'm trying to fade out a `UILabel` which has been added as a `UIViewController`'s navigation item's `titleView`. On iOS 11 and below, the following code correctly fades out the label. When run on iOS 12, the fade *in* animation works, but the fade *out* does not animate - the view disappears immediately.

```
let fadeTextAnimation = CATransition()
fadeTextAnimation.type = .fade
fadeTextAnimation.duration = 0.5

navigationItem.titleView!.layer.add(fadeTextAnimation, forKey: nil)
(navigationItem.titleView as! UILabel).isHidden = didShowNavigationItemTitle
```

I've also tried changing the code to use `UIView.transition`, but the same behaviour is observed.

```
UIView.transition(with: navigationItem.titleView!,
    duration: 0.5,
    options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
    animations: {
        (self.navigationItem.titleView as! UILabel).isHidden = self.didShowNavigationItemTitle
    }, completion: nil)
```

How can one achieve this fade out in iOS 12?

Comment: Have you tried other animations type / subtypes? Do they have similar problems?

Comment: I have now tried a few other animation types: they seem to animate out correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `UIView.animate` block and animate the alpha of the title view.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.navigationItem.titleView?.alpha = 0
})
```

Comment: This does indeed correctly animate, but I hit some other difficulties with using the `alpha` property rather than `isHidden`. I want to open the view with the label hidden, but for some reason, setting a navigation item's `titleView` to have an `alpha` of `0` during `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` does not take effect (or rather, it appears that something is making the navigationItem's titleView opaque shortly after the view is loaded)

Comment: This is, I suppose, an answer to _this_ question; perhaps I will raise the other issues as another question